# First Activity is recreating when setResult() back to first Activity from second Activity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

In my first `Activity` I am starting an intent to second `Activity` with `startActivityForResult()` ,then from second `Activity` I am sending some data back to `FirstActivity` with `setResult()` and but when `onActivityResult()` is called, `FirstActivity` is creating again and refreshing completely so a I am losing all the data send from second `Activity`.

`FirstActivity` extends `FragmentActivity`.

This issue I am observing in One plus 3 device of one user but I am having same device with same configuration I am getting this issue So I am suspecting issue could be with SDK . Can you please check and suggest some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the code where you are starting and finishing the activity.

Comment: Provide a code and also how your activities are declared in the manifest.

Comment: I have a strong feeling you are calling `startActivity()` after `setResult()`. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check one thing in your Phone setting, it might be related to this:

Go to Setting->Developer Options->Don't keep activities(if it is checked then uncheck it)
after uncheck "Don't keep activities" run your application again, Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: you are welcome :), if it is helpful could you please upvote my answer ?